# Is "Earth is full! Go Home!" an example of sarcasm? If so, why?

Tags: meaning, irony

Is "Earth is full! Go Home!" an example of sarcasm?

If it is, I'd really like someone to explain why this is sarcastic. From all the definitions I've seen for sarcasm, I've gathered that sarcasm means saying something opposite to what is meant intending to criticize, be funny, hurtful, etc. I don't get the *opposite* part in this example I've given. Maybe it's a different type of sarcasm?

Comment: Where is the example from? Why do you think it might be sarcasm in this case?

Comment: I was given this example by an English teacher as an example of sarcasm.

Comment: Whether it is sarcasm would depend on the context.

Comment: Alright, so in what context would it be sarcastic?

Comment: I'm not going to waste my imagination thinking up a context for you. But consider that sarcasm involves irony, not just a critical response. For example, the positive statement, "Yeah, right!" could be simple agreement (if the plain answer to a question would be "yes") or sarcasm (if the answer would be obviously "no").

Comment: You said it depends on the context, so I thought you'd have an idea of the context. I didn't think it would be difficult. I understand the example you've provided. I've done some research on the topic in an attempt to answer my question. My search tells me no. But I'd prefer to get an answer from an expert. I'm hoping this forum is the place for that. I'm really looking for a yes or no answer with an explanation. And if someone can imagine a context where it is sarcastic, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: It depends  if it's directed at someone who actually can go home. If not, it might be mocking. Sarcasm doesn't have to involve saying the opposite (irony), although it often does - see the Wikipedia entry (you claim to have looked at all the definitions of sarcasm but I guess not that one).

Comment: Imagine an alien (extraterrestrial) who wants to emigrate here (planet earth). You tell the alien to leave because earth is full. Is it "sarcastic" though?

Comment: In that case, no, it's very literal.

Comment: If you split the phrase, is either 'Earth is full…' or 'Go Home…' by itself sarcastic - or mocking, or satirical? How does your teacher suggest they become sarcastic by being joined?

Answer (score -1):

> Is"Earth is full! Go Home!" an example of sarcasm?

No. You seem to understand what sarcasm is, and its definition. Your example is not sarcasm.

If I had to categorise it, I would call it satire.

OED **Satire**

> **I. A literary composition, and related senses.**
>
> **1.a. A poem or** (in later use) **a novel, film, or other work of art which uses humour, irony, exaggeration, or ridicule to expose and
> criticize prevailing immorality or foolishness, esp. as a form of
> social or political commentary.**
>
> 1948   Jrnl. Aesthetics & Art Crit. 7 148   *Proudhon admires the same
> picture because it is a telling satire of the corrupt bourgeoisie.*